# How do i ask user for a marker icon type?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, prompt

I managed to ask the user for Lat and lNG, but I can;t seem to ask user for the icon type of the marker.

The icon is currently set at

```
icon: lH
```

the choices are: lN, lH and lC as you can see a bit further down, I've tried using the prompt var and setting it as an icon but that didn't work

```
  var icons = prompt("lH, lN, or lC", "lC");
  icon: icons
```

can anyone help ?

```
 function newqMarker( width, height ) {



          lN = new google.maps.MarkerImage( 'http://www.schweizer-brandschutz.ch/media/image/google-marker.png',
      new google.maps.Size( 32, 37 ),
      new google.maps.Point( 0, 0 ), 
      new google.maps.Point( 16, 35 ) );

      lH = new google.maps.MarkerImage( 'http://www.andersiahotel.pl/img/marker-small.png', 
      new google.maps.Size( 32, 37 ), 
      new google.maps.Point( 0, 0 ),
      new google.maps.Point( 16, 35 ) );

      lC = new google.maps.MarkerImage( 'https://oge.com/images/blueMarker.png',
      new google.maps.Size( 20, 32 ),
      new google.maps.Point( 0, 0 ),
      new google.maps.Point( 16, 35  ) );

      var person = prompt("lH, lN, or lC", "lC");

        markere = new google.maps.Marker( {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng( prompt( "Latitude: " ), prompt( "Longtitude: " ) ),
            map: map,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            icon: lH,
            title: 'I am here'
        } );
        google.maps.event.addListener( markere, 'click', toggleBounce );
        google.maps.event.addListener( markere, 'click', function() {
            InfoWindowe.open( map, markere )
        } );



  google.maps.event.addListener(markere, 'mouseover', function(){this.setIcon(lH)});
 google.maps.event.addListener(markere, 'mouseout', function(){this.setIcon(lN)});
 google.maps.event.addListener(markere, 'mousedown', function(){this.setIcon(lC)});
 google.maps.event.addListener(markere, 'mouseup', function(){this.setIcon(lH)});


  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An icon is a complex object, it can't be returned by the `prompt`, but you can add a `switch` statement to set that property from the string returned by the `prompt`:

```
var person = prompt("lH, lN, or lC", "lC");
var icon = lH;
switch (person) {
  case "lH":
    icon = lH;
    break;
  case "lN":
    icon = lN;
    break;
  case "lC":
  default:
    icon = lC;
    break;
}

var markere = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(prompt("Latitude: "), prompt("Longtitude: ")),
  map: map,
  animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
  icon: icon,
  title: 'I am here'
});
google.maps.event.addListener(markere, 'click', toggleBounce);
google.maps.event.addListener(markere, 'click', function() {
  InfoWindowe.open(map, markere)
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/jy73L7dp/1/)

**Note:** the `MarkerImage` class was deprecated after v3.10 (really long time ago ~2012/2013):

from [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#complex_icons)

> **Converting MarkerImage objects to type Icon**
>
> Until version 3.10 of the Google Maps JavaScript API, complex icons were defined as MarkerImage objects. The Icon object literal was added in version 3.10, and replaces MarkerImage from version 3.11 onwards.

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  newqMarker(0, 0);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

function newqMarker(width, height) {
  lN = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://www.schweizer-brandschutz.ch/media/image/google-marker.png',
    new google.maps.Size(32, 37),
    new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    new google.maps.Point(16, 35));

  lH = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://www.andersiahotel.pl/img/marker-small.png',
    new google.maps.Size(32, 37),
    new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    new google.maps.Point(16, 35));

  lC = new google.maps.MarkerImage('https://oge.com/images/blueMarker.png',
    new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
    new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    new google.maps.Point(16, 35));

  var person = prompt("lH, lN, or lC", "lC");
  var icon = lH;
  switch (person) {
    case "lH":
      icon = lH;
      break;
    case "lN":
      icon = lN;
      break;
    case "lC":
    default:
      icon = lC;
      break;
  }

  markere = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(prompt("Latitude: ", "37.4419"), prompt("Longtitude: ", "-122.1419")),
    map: map,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    icon: icon,
    title: 'I am here'
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(markere, 'mouseover', function() {
    this.setIcon(lH)
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(markere, 'mouseout', function() {
    this.setIcon(lN)
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(markere, 'mousedown', function() {
    this.setIcon(lC)
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(markere, 'mouseup', function() {
    this.setIcon(lH)
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```